# TensorFlow Keras Models Cannot Predict on Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make predictions with a TensorFlow Keras model asynchronously.  The model runs normally without multiprocessing, however, as soon as it is called with mp.Process, it never runs.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def predict(data):
    a = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(16,))])

    return a.predict(data)

fake_data = np.zeros((100, 16))

# Works
for i in range(4):
    print(predict(fake_data).shape)

# Never finishes running
processes = []
for i in range(4):
    p = mp.Process(target=predict, args=(fake_data,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Why does this happen?  Are there workarounds/am I doing something wrong? I've tried wrapping the inside of `predict` with `with tf.device('/cpu:0')`, but the problem persists.

EDIT: The problem seems to happen regardless of TF 1 or 2

Comment: Why do you want to predict with multiprocessing? Keras predict API has `workers` and `use_multiprocessing` parameter which you need to use keras.utils.Sequence input or generators. You might find that helpful.

Comment: I need to have different models predicting asynchronously.  That's why the `predict` function instantiates a new model for each prediction, instead of having a global model.